How to expire a status (any field) after some time in golang using scyllaDB?
I want to expire a status field in my users table, just like how slack expires a status after the expiry set by the user.
I have integrated scylla cdc but scylla cdc does not give me the updated response after status is expired.
My project's language is golang and DB is scylla. So anyone have any other idea than this, please suggest.
I have tried integrating scylla cdc but it did not returns me updated result after a status is expired (used TTL in the query), I was expecting that scylla cdc will give me a response than I will send that response to my server to notify other users but it did not happened.

You are right, ScyllaDB's CDC does not send events for the eventual expiration of data. You get the event about the change that originally set the data, and this event contains the full TTL information about when this data is set to expire - but you don't get an additional event when (say) a week later the data really expires. This is a known limitation of ScyllaDB, see for example issue #8380.
This fact is not a simple bug or oversight, and will be hard to fix because of how TTL works in ScyllaDB (and Cassandra), and also how CDC works in ScyllaDB:

ScyllaDB's TTL does not use an expensive background thread, or queues or timers or anything of that sort to actively look for expired data and delete it. Rather, only when you try to read expired data, it is filtered out from the results, and only eventually when data is compacted the expired data is really deleted from disk. This means that if some data expires
midnight January 1st, there isn't any Scylla process that notices that this date of midnight January 1st has arrived and can generate the CDC event. It is quite possible that until February no read or compaction will even try to read this data and notice it had already expired.
Even if you're content to get the expiration event delayed, only when compaction finally notices it (note that this can be arbitrarily long delay!), the problem is that different replicas of the data (you have RF, usually 3, copies of the same data) will notice this at different times. Scylla's CDC can't work this way: It needs the same event to appear on the RF replicas at roughly the same time.
Finally, note that Scylla's TTL feature is per cell (value of a single column) - a row doesn't need to expire entirely at one time, and pieces of it can expire at different times. Even if CDC could send such events, they would look rather odd - not a row deletion but deletions of pieces of the row.

All of the above is about Scylla's CQL and CDC. But Scylla also has support for the DynamoDB API (this feature is known as ScyllaDB Alternator), and the DynamoDB API does have Streams (their version of CDC) and TTL on entire rows, and does expiration events on CDC. So how does Scylla implement this? It turns out that to implement this, Scylla indeed uses a background thread that actively looks for expired items, and deletes them while creating CDC events.
In issue #13000 I proposed to expose this alternative TTL implementation also for CQL. It will behave differently from the existing CQL TTL, and have lower performance - but some might argue it will be more useful.
